# Passed value to js function seems to be null, while it's not

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, razor

these are the functions that i'm actually using to call specific api from js:

```
function SuspendActionOp(barcode, owner) {
//alert(barcode+" - "+num);
alert(owner);
if (owner == null) {
    alert('owner is null');
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver/myapp/api/Actions?action=2&barcode=' + barcode + '&owner=' + owner,
        //data: { id: barcode },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (a) {
            //var t = JSON.parse(a);
            if (a.result.localeCompare("suspended") == 0) {
                $("#details_" + barcode).modal("hide");
                setTimeout(MachinesBigOp(), 2000);
            } else {
                alert("Error");
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

This function is called by (and owner is valued):

```
function ActionsOp(stato, barcode, num, owner) {
alert('ActionsOp '+owner);
var btngroup = document.createElement('div');
btngroup.classList.add("btn-group");

switch (stato) {

    case 1:
        var s = document.createElement("a");            
        s.onclick = function () {
            //var t = owner;
            alert(owner);
            SuspendActionOp(barcode, num, owner);
        };
        s.classList.add("btn");
        s.classList.add("btn-warning");
        s.innerHTML = "❚❚";

        btngroup.appendChild(s);
        var e = document.createElement("a");

        e.classList.add("btn");
        e.classList.add("btn-danger");
        e.innerHTML = "✔";
        e.onclick = function () {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(ModalEndOp(barcode, owner));
            $('#end_' + barcode).modal({ backdrop: false });
        };
        e.style.marginLeft = "40px";
        btngroup.appendChild(e);
        break;
    case 2:
        var a = document.createElement("a");

        a.onclick = function () {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(ModalStartOp(barcode, owner));
            $("#start_" + barcode).modal({ backdrop: false });
        };
        a.classList.add("btn");
        a.classList.add("btn-success");
        a.innerHTML = "⚡";
        btngroup.appendChild(a);
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
}
return btngroup;
}
```

from:

```
function ModalDetailsOp(num, owner) {
    alert('ModalDetailsOp' + owner);  
   //.........
   var azioni = document.createElement('td');
   azioni.appendChild(ActionsOp(a[i].Stato, a[i].Barcode, a[i].NumMachine, owner));
    //.........
}
```

from:

```
    function MachinesBigOp(owner) {
        alert('MachinesBigOp'+owner);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetMachines',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (a) {

                var cont = document.getElementById("machineContainer");
                cont.innerHTML = "";
                var l = a.length;
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    var m = document.createElement("a");
                    m.classList.add('machine');
                    m.classList.add('hover-shadow');
                    m.classList.add('show');
                    m.style.color = "black";
                    cont.appendChild(ModalDetailsOp(a[i].NumMachine,owner));
//.....
}
```

and finally from html razor page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        filterSelection("all");
        filterInit();
        MachinesBigOp('@Session["id"].ToString()');
    });

</script>
```

But it looks like that when i pass the `owner` variable with its value and when the `SuspendActionOp()` is called, the owner value is null.
I can't find out where the problem is.
Thanks for helping

Comment: You are calling `SuspendActionOp(barcode, num, owner)` with three params but you are expecting only two `function SuspendActionOp(barcode, owner) {`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm afraid the above is too fragmentary for us to help you. What is `a` in `ModalDetailsOp`?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SuspendActionOp` function is defined with 2 parameters

```
SuspendActionOp(barcode, owner)
```

but your calling it with 3 parameters from `ActionsOp`

```
SuspendActionOp(barcode, num, owner);
```

So, obviously in this case `num` will be having the `owner` value!

Comment: Based on the parameter names, this could be it. If so, I'd say that's typo-territory...